# Drop-down menu using button, hovering over one button displays blocks from all buttons

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to create a menu where there are 3 buttons horizontally and when hovering over each button, it should show the block listing the various sub-menu option under that button. The only problem I am facing with the below code is:

1. When I hover over the last button in the row, then it shows the drop-down submenu options from the "all the three" button.
2. When I hover on the first button it correctly shows the sub-menu of only that button, when when I transition my hover to the second button in the row, then the sub-menu displayed for the first button doesn't close itself (instead now both buttons are showing the sub-menu drop-down expanded).

Here's the simple code I have:

```css
<style type="text/css"> 
.dropbtn-01 {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: yellow;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.dropdown-01 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative
}
.dropdown-content-01 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    min-width: 10px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content-01 a {
    color: black;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content-01 a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
.dropdown-01:hover .dropdown-content-01 {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-01:hover .dropbtn-01 {
    background-color: grey;
}
.dropbtn-02 {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: yellow;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.dropdown-02 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative
}
.dropdown-content-02 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    min-width: 30px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
.dropdown-content-02 a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content-02 a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
.dropdown-02:hover .dropdown-content-02 {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-02:hover .dropbtn-02 {
    background-color: grey;
}

.dropbtn-03 {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: yellow;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.dropdown-03 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative
}
.dropdown-content-03 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    min-width: 30px;
    display: none;
    z-index: 3;
}
.dropdown-content-03 a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content-03 a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
.dropdown-03:hover .dropdown-content-03 {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-03:hover .dropbtn-03 {
    background-color: grey;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-01"><span><button class="dropbtn-01">Main</button> </span>
<div class="dropdown-content-01"><span><a href="Link-1">Home</a> <a href="Link-2">The Mama</a> &lt; </span></div>

<span style="display:inline-block; width: 60px;"></span>
<div class="dropdown-02"><span><button class="dropbtn-02">About</button> </span>
<div class="dropdown-content-02"><span><a href="Link-3">Credentials</a> <a href="Link-4">Aboutx</a> &lt; </span></div>


<span style="display:inline-block; width: 60px;"></span>
<div class="dropdown-03"><span><button class="dropbtn-03">Contact</button> </span>
<div class="dropdown-content-03"><span><a href="Link-5">Contact Us</a> &lt; </span></div>
```

Comment: parent div's must be closed, to see accurate result

Answer (score 0):

You have no closing tags for some of your `div` containers. e.g. You didn't close your first `div` container with the class `dropdown-01`. I've cleaned up your code and removed unnecessary tags. See the snippet below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.dropbtn-01 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown-01 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative
}

.dropdown-content-01 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-width: 10px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content-01 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content-01 a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.dropdown-01:hover .dropdown-content-01 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-01:hover .dropbtn-01 {
  background-color: grey;
}

.dropbtn-02 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.dropdown-02 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative
}

.dropdown-content-02 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-width: 30px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dropdown-content-02 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content-02 a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.dropdown-02:hover .dropdown-content-02 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-02:hover .dropbtn-02 {
  background-color: grey;
}

.dropbtn-03 {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.dropdown-03 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative
}

.dropdown-content-03 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  min-width: 30px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.dropdown-content-03 a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content-03 a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.dropdown-03:hover .dropdown-content-03 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-03:hover .dropbtn-03 {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdown-01">
    <button class="dropbtn-01">Main</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-01"><a href="Link-1">Home</a> <a href="Link-2">The Mama</a> &lt;
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-02">
    <button class="dropbtn-02">About</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-02"><a href="Link-3">Credentials</a> <a href="Link-4">Aboutx</a> &lt;
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-03">
    <button class="dropbtn-03">Contact</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content-03"><a href="Link-5">Contact Us</a> &lt;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank-you so much, Yong. This worked perfectly.